# Is my simplification correct?

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

I was solving questions related to the `properties of triangles` and I am stuck here.

This is the question,

[image]

I am solving this question like this

[image]

But none of the options matched and I found a different answer on the web.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Typically, this kind of question wants you to use an angle formula like $tan(\frac{A-B}{2}) = \frac{sinA-sinB}{cosA+cosB}$ and avoid finding any angle explicitely

Comment: I found one website with a similar question, but in their question, the value of $\angle A$ was given $60^o$. So of course their answer is 1. Can you reveal the source of the image you posted?

Comment: your answer seems valid...

Comment: question is of a pdf from an institute.

Comment: Your answer is correct. For a simpler way to arrive at this result, use Napier's Analogy